# String "de-concatenation"

Tags: c#, string

I have two strings like this

```
string s = "abcdef";
string t = "def";
```

I would like to remove t from s.  Can I do this like this?

```
s = s - t?
```

**EDIT**

I will have two strings s and t, t will be an ending substring of s.  I want to remove t from s.

Comment: No, that won't work. Is the string you want to remove always "def"? Or is it the last three letters of the string? Will that suffix always be present?

Comment: Decatenation *is* a [jargon] word, but .. not appropriate discipline/usage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, but you can do this:

```
var newStr = "abcdef".Replace("def", "");
```

Per your comments, if you want to only remove the trailing pattern you can use a Regex:

```
var newStr = Regex.Replace("defdefdef", "(def)$", "");
```

The '$' will anchor to the end of the string, so it will only remove the final 'def'

Turning this into an extension method:

```
public static String ReplaceEnd(this string input, string subStr, string replace = "")
{
    //Per Alexei Levenkov's comments, the string should
    // be escaped in order to avoid accidental injection
    // of special characters into the Regex pattern
    var escaped = Regex.Escape(subStr);

    var pattern = String.Format("({0})$", escaped);
    return Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replace);
}
```

Using this method with your code above would become:

```
string s = "abcdef";
string t = "def";

s = s.ReplaceEnd(t); // Ta Da!
```

Comment: No, you see def could appear elsewhere in the string.  I simply want to remove the end part of the string.

Comment: Josh is correct: there is no built in "string subtract".  "String.Replace()" might be one solution.  A combination of "String.LastIndexOf()" and "String.Substring()" might be a solution for the qualified requirements you responded with.  Using a [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx) might be yet another solution.  You have plenty of options :)

Comment: +1 for complete answer. Also demonstration of "sql injection" based on regular expressions is of questionable value: `"foo".ReplaceEnd("..")` is not exactly what one would expect :).

Comment: I did not use "sql injection" in relation to SQL, but rather as "using incorrectly escaped data in execution of queries in a query language"... Clearly bad choice of words... will remove both comments soon.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I see what you mean now in that someone could pass in a string that would be interpreted by the Regex parser, and therefore produce unexpected results. I've updated the answer to incorporate your feedback.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
if (s.EndsWith(t))
{
    s = s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf(t));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
s = s.Substring(0, s.Length - t.Length)
```

`Substring` takes two arguments: start and length. You want to take things from the start of `abcdef`, that's index `0`, and you want to take all the characters minus the characters from `t`, which is the difference of length of the two strings.

This assumes the OP's contract of "t will be an ending substring of s". If in fact this precondition is not guaranteed, it needs `if (s.EndsWith(t))` around it.

Comment: @paulsm4: I understood the OP's "t will be an ending substring of s" as a contract, thus did not think a guard would be necessary (i.e. it would be taken care of elsewhere).